# WIX Installing windows service

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6

I am trying to install windows services using WIX. The windows services are installing fine and if I check inside Service Manager I am able to see that my services are installed and are trying to start as shown below:

[image: logservice]

After 3 to 4 minutes I am getting error sufficient privileges required. Please see the image for the error message:

[image: setupinstalling]

If I run my windows services setup manually then it's installing fine without any problem in starting up. What I am doing wrong can anyone help?

Following is the code that I am using:

```
public ProjectInstaller()
        {this.ServiceProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.ServiceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            // 
            // ServiceProcessInstaller
            // 
            this.ServiceProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
            this.ServiceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            this.ServiceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            // 
            // ServiceInstaller
            // 
            this.ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "Service";
            this.ServiceInstaller.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        }
```

Following is my WIX code:

```
<File Id='SetupService' Name='SetupService' DiskId='1' Source='setup.exe' KeyPath='yes'/>
 <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"   Type="ownProcess" Name="SetupService" DisplayName="DataLogsetup" Description="Service" Start="auto" Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" ErrorControl="normal"/>
 <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="SetupService" Wait="yes" />
```

I have also tried to pass in [LocalService] in the Account, but still I am getting the same error. Is there anyway I can install my service using WIX?

Answer (score 2):

I see several reasons which may lead to failure here:

1. You are not calling

   `Installers.Add(this.ServiceInstaller);
   Installers.Add(this.ServiceProcessInstaller);`

at the end of your method. `The Installers.Add(..)` line should actually add the service to service table. [See the example at the end of this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.aspx)

1. As far as I know, Installer classes are not supported in WIX, Custom Actions are used instead. How do you call your code from WIX?
2. WIX has a `<ServiceInstall>` element for installing services. Although not allmighty, this element is very powerful and the preferred method to install Windows Services. See [Installing and starting a Windows Service using WiX](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx)

Comment: :Thank you for the reply.I could able to install the service.As i done few changes inside product.wxs. Provide below the working one.

Comment: <File Id="Setup.exe" Name="Setup.exe" Source="setup.exe"  DiskId='1' KeyPath='yes' />
<ServiceInstall Id="InstallWixService" DisplayName="Setup" Name="Setup.exe" Description="Running the sample windows service using wix" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" />
                      <ServiceControl Id="ControlWixService" Name="Setup.exe" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" />